# Get the total earnings from a specific URL using the Adsense Management API

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

Is it possible to get the total all-time earnings of a specific URL (say, https://example.com/page/xyz) using the AdSense Management API? (preferably the PHP library).

If so, please post a code answer or atleast a concept of how it could be implemented.

*BTW, the number of ad units or any specific ad units dont matter; I just want the total income from a specific URL on my site using the API*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL Channels](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1064705) to declare the specific pages you want to track, and then in the API you can include the URL_CHANNEL_ID or URL_CHANNEL_NAME dimension in your report to break down by URL.

Once your URL Channels are set up, you can check out the [AdSense API example repository](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples) to see how to run a report. This repository has different folders for different PHP versions. Choose the folder corresponding to your version, then go to `examples/GenerateReport.php` for a starting point. The AdSense API docs have a full list of [Dimensions and Metrics](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/metrics-dimensions) and the [full report specification](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate) in case you want to make other changes.

Comment: But Adsense only allows me to create a maximum of 500 URL channels, which is way less than the number of pages I'll need to track since my site has mostly user-created content. My intention is to track the total earnings and pay a part of the revenue to the user who created the page, but URL channels would only allow upto 500. Is there any other way? Maybe using Analytics?